SVM model always predicts the same value no matter the features
I am using SVM to predict if a change in error is good or bad i.e. (good = negative value and good = positive value converted to a boolean).
Now, I split my data per category. Every category has at least 10 or more rows.
Within the dataset, I have multiple sets of features. (26 columns times 9)
My 'problem' is, that there is almost no difference in the accuracy of the prediction based on the set of features that are going in to model.
The accuracy is however different per category, but within a category, there is almost no difference.
My features can be seen as a polynomial (parabola) over the 26 columns, so the data points of each row have the characteristics of a parabola. Is there any other approach I must take considering this?


Every category has at least 10 or more rows.
Within the dataset, I have multiple sets of features. (26 columns times 9)

SVMs can overfit quite easily, especially when samples are few and there are lots of features. Both seem to be potential issues for the dataset you describe. A simpler model like LogisticRegression/LogisticRegressionCV or LinearSVC might generalise better.

My 'problem' is, that there is almost no difference in the accuracy of the prediction based on the set of features that are going in to model.
The accuracy is however different per category, but within a category, there is almost no difference.

If I understood correctly, you are fitting one model for each of the 9 feature sets, and you are expecting some of those models to do better than others? You're finding that for any given category, all of the models perform the same, but the performance is different for separate categories?

My features can be seen as a polynomial (parabola) over the 26 columns, so the data points of each row have the characteristics of a parabola. Is there any other approach I must take considering this?

Perhaps you could compress the 26 features down to just a few coefficients that characterise the polynomial? If it's a quadratic profile for example, you could fit a curve to determine the quadratic's 3 coefficients, and use those values for each sample rather than the 26 features. This reduces the dimensionality of the input data whilst preserving its salient features (if it is quadratic), which helps mitigate overfitting for small datasets.
